# How do I debug on-chip with Arduino?

Tags: ide, emulation, debugging

Though an emulator is quite useful for debugging code that has no side effects, most real-world applications include some circuitry besides the Arduino. If a microcontroller on an Arduino had a JTAG interface, it would be pretty straight-forward, but what if it's e.g. an Arduino Uno?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Its not clear from the question that what exactly do you want to debug.

Comment: @AsheeshR The only thing that is possible to debug on Arduino is source code. There's a set of tools called "debuggers", which employ breakpoints, step-by-step evaluation etc. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @jippie You're wrong about that. DebugWire yes, but JTAG No. The ATMega168/368 has no JTAG support whatsoever. If you do a quick search of the datasheet you will not find any reference to JTAG

Comment: @Madivad Is it possible to make another Arduino into USB to DebugWire connector?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I have never used DebugWire, so I don't know the first thing about it. I just did a quick google search, and there is stuff out there, so have a look at that. I have only ever used the JTAG pre Arduino days (ATMega128).

Comment: DebugWire is an Atmel proprietary protocol, not much information available about it.

Comment: I would say you don't. The closest to debugging I've seem is having the Arduino listen to serial and perform commands (like e.g. variable dumping) on request.

Comment: It seems there is possibility for interactive debugging with this tool: http://www.visualmicro.com/post/2012/05/05/Debug-Arduino-Overview.aspx it is not free but it is quite cheap. I haven't used it myself so I don't want to provide an answer for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Arduino Uno uses the Atmel Atmega328p microcontroller, which only has one debug option, DebugWire.  There are a few tools that can work with it, but the least expensive and most commonly available is the [AVR Dragon](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AVRDRAGON.aspx).

You can use AVR Studio 6 for this.  You can use the `.elf` file file produced during the Arduino build process directly, but setting up the debugger is a little easier if you port the Arduino program to the AVR Studio.  It's not difficult, but there are a lot of little pieces to deal with.  There are guides online to help you through this.

Comment: Is there an AVR Dragon clone with open-source firmware?

Comment: Any links to those online guides?

Comment: There are MKII clones which will do debugwire with this chip, but I'm not aware of their open source hardware or software status, and am having trouble finding a good example easily. Here's one guide for using AVR Studio 6 with arduino projects: http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/

Comment: Doesn't this require  [removing a capacitor](https://awtfy.com/2010/02/21/modify-an-arduino-for-debugwire/)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't know, you'd have to examine the arduino uno schematic and the debugwire requirements along with your debugger's documentation. It may be worth asking a new question to get or share details of a specific setup.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be right for you, but the [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com/) plugin for Atmel Studio and Visual Studio has a [USB debugger](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Debugging-for-Arduino.aspx) which only uses Arduino code.

In the background the debugger uses Serial which might affect some time-sensitive applications.

[image]

Comment: Will this really work on Arduino Uno?